# Dart: warning "info: This function has a return type of 'int', but doesn't end with a return statement")

Tags: flutter, dart

I got a warning on the following piece of code, and I don't know why.

```dart
List<Map<String, int>> callNoInfo = [];

int getCallNo(String phoneNo) {
  callNoInfo.forEach((item) {
    if (item.containsKey(phoneNo)) {
      return item[phoneNo];
    }
  });
  return 0;
}
```

The warning is:

```
This function has a return type of 'int', but doesn't end with a return statement. (missing_return at [project_name] lib\helper\call_no.dart:35)
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens? thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know Dart, but it looks like when the `if` block isn't entered, there is no `return` in that `forEach` block, and that is probably what the warning is about.

Comment: Actually there is a return at the end. The actually problem is that I cannot do a return in the loop forEach(), please check the answer from Abion47.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `forEach` method, you are creating a lambda function without explicitly defining the return type, so Dart is attempting to infer it from the `return` statements. If we pull the function out of the `forEach` method, it might help to see what I mean:

```dart
...
(item) {
  if (item.containsKey(phoneNo)) {
    return item[phoneNo];
  }
}
...
```

The function includes a `return` statement that returns `item[phoneNo]`, which is an `int` value. Using this, Dart infers that the return type of this lambda function is `int`. However, now that it knows this, it also notices that if the code execution does not enter the `if` block, there is no `return` statement to match the `else` side of the `if` condition. If the `item` object does not contain the key `phoneNo`, what is the method going to return?

*(The answer is that the method will implicitly return `null` which is why the message is only a warning and not a compiler error, but the warning appears because this probably wasn't intentional by you the developer and also as a nudge to help you make your code less reliant on invisible Dart runtime magicks.)*

To fix this, there needs to be another `return` outside of the `if` block:

```dart
...
(item) {
  if (item.containsKey(phoneNo)) {
    return item[phoneNo];
  }
  return 0;
}
...
```

However, now there's a different problem. The `forEach` method on lists has the following signature:

```
forEach(void f(E element)) → void
```

In fact, there are two problems. First, the method passed as the parameter needs to have a return type of `void`, and the `forEach` method itself also has a return type of `void`. This means that **you cannot return values from within the `forEach` method at all.**

The thing about the `forEach` method is that it is intended to iterate over the collection and process each of the values within it. It's not meant to (and can't) search for a value and return it once it's found. Furthermore, the iteration is exhaustive, meaning once you start it, the method cannot be stopped until each and every element in the collection has been iterated over.

Which is why, as the other answers have pointed out, what you really should be doing is using a `for` or `for in` loop:

```dart
List<Map<String, int>> callNoInfo = [];

int getCallNo(String phoneNo) {
  for(var item in callNoInfo) {
    if (item.containsKey(phoneNo)) {
      return item[phoneNo];
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

*(I'm not sure why you don't get a compiler error for assigning a lambda function with a return value of `int` to the `forEach` method which clearly is requesting a one with a `void` return type. But if I had to guess, I'd say the Dart runtime treats them as compatible and reconciles the difference in return type by simply discarding the return value of the lambda function.)*

Comment: Very clear explanation, thank you so much for the insight!

Answer (score -1):

You don't have an else case for the if statement inside the `forEach` loop. Even though you might have one at the end, it still is expecting a case everywhere.

```
List<Map<String, int>> callNoInfo = [];
int getCallNo(String phoneNo) {
  callNoInfo.forEach((item) {
    if (item.containsKey(phoneNo)) {
      return item[phoneNo];
    }
    // you don't have a case for here since it's in a callback
  });
  return 0;
}
```

However, you could do this which uses a `for in` loop:

```
List<Map<String, int>> callNoInfo = [];
int getCallNo(String phoneNo) {
  for (var item in callNoInfo) {
    if (item.containsKey(phoneNo)) {
      return item[phoneNo];
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is even worse than before.

Comment: I had edited my answer but I reversed it now @creativecreatorormaybenot